# 404 not found when calling servlet from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my servlet, the path define like this:

```
@WebServlet("/checklogin")
```

from jsp i call this servlet by

```
<form id="login-form" name="login" action="checklogin" method="post">
```

deploy to `localhost`, it running perfect, but from a real server, it keep saying **404 file not found error**.

file structures:

```
           ---->index.jsp
           ---->admin.jsp
project1   ---->WEB-INF -- > classes ---> project1 ----> checklogin.class
           ---->META-INF
```

Comment: The question is how you deploy it, under which context name.

Comment: @Leos Literak I use eclipse deploy it, it will auto sync to my local server, and i just copy all content from my local server to real server

Comment: what is name of war file? Is it same on both machines?

Comment: @Leos Literak actually there is no war file

Comment: can you open index.jsp?

Comment: so is it exploded war directory?

Comment: @Leos Literak yes i can, just when i try to login, it cannot find checklogin class

Comment: @Leos Literak i think so

Comment: @Leos Literak if i export the project1 as project1.war, where should i put this war file?

Comment: Add a parameterless constructor with a log statement. Also make your servlet load on startup. Start your webapp and check if the log statement was printed.

Comment: What application server do you use? Because you use annotation, the server must support servlet 3.0. Try to add empty web.xml with 3.0 version, it may help.

Answer (score 1):

add a `/` before ref on jsp:

```
<form id="login-form" name="login" action="/checklogin" method="post">
```

Comment: What will this change and how does it explain the behavior they are currently seeing?

Comment: Unless war is deployed as root application this answer is wrong.

Comment: I've try project1/checklogin /project1/checklogin /checklogin, all not working